# Use SUMIF with transformed text to number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a monthly budget in Excel that I'm using to keep track of making sure all of my recurring bills get paid on time.

Let's assume I have a table formatted like this:

`Bill       | Due Date | Amount Projected | Actual Amount | Diff
Mortgage   | 1st      | $1,500           | $1,510        | -$10
Water Bill | 13th     | $30              | $25.80        | $4.20`

I get paid on the 1st and the 15th, and I'm trying to get two rows that give a sum of all of the bills that are due within the first paycheck, and a sum of those that are due after.

So I'm trying to use the SUMIF function, however because the DUE DATE column is text and not date so that I get the 1st, 2nd, etc, I'm not sure how to run a comparison on this.

So I have the formula to get rid of the `th`, `nd`, etc as:

`=LEFT(B2, LEN(B2)-2)`

If it didn't have the `th`, or `nd`, the SUMIF function would look like this:

`=SUMIF(C2:C3, "> 15", B2:B3)`

But I just can't figure out how to combine the two formula.  Is there any special character that runs the transform on the cell where I can pass that into the formula, without having an intermediate cell somewhere to just hold the `1`, or `13` for the date due?

I know there are *other ways* to do this like just sorting the columns by due date and then only selecting that range, but I'd like to not have to manually change a bunch of other "reporting" columns every time I add or remove a bill.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((left(B2:B3,len(B2:B3)-2)<15)*C2:C3)
```

SUMPRODUCT performs array like operations.  As such avoid using full column reference such as B:B.

Comment: Ahh, this was very close, but 99% of the way there.  I used `FLOOR` to translate the `1st` value into `1`, as without the `FLOOR` function I think it was still translating into a string.

Thanks!

Comment: So the final function ended up being something like this: `=SUMPRODUCT((FLOOR(LEFT(B2:B3, LEN(B2:B3)-2)<15))*C2:C3)`

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((--(left(B2:B3,len(B2:B3)-2))<15)*C2:C3)` would work too.  Any time you send a number as a string through a math operation its converted to a number automatically.